# Deleting all elements with the attribute value cite_ in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I have the following code:

```
document.querySelectorAll(" img, [href='#cite'] ").forEach(function(el) {
    el.style.display = "none";
});
```

In this code you can see the *attribute-value* wildcard `[href='#cite-']`.

This selector resembles source citations in Wikipedia articles.

The above code doesn't work so all elements with any element containing an `href` **starting with cite** aren't deleted.

[This is the page I work on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Healthcare_in_Russia) - You could see that all source-references and notes (these are called "citations" in general, hence the term "cite") have this href value of citeSOMETHING.

My question is if it is even possible to target all `a` tags with the href attribute and all values starting with cite.

Comment: What do you mean by "wildcard selector"?

Comment: You meant to the title and 1 place in the question; This stayed from when I meant to ask about a CSS wildcard which I already used successfully. I now fixed the question. The phrasing "wildcard selector" is a mistake, I should fix that, I guess, to "attribute-value wildcard").

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by "wildcard" there. `[href='#cite-']` finds all elements whose `href` attribute is exactly `"#cite-"`.

Comment: Yes, and I need a wildcard so that everything that starts with this phrase "cite-" will be targeted, as the Wiki article has some variations with this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [attribute starts with selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to select all elements where attribute value starts with a certain value.

```
document.querySelectorAll("img,[href^='#cite'] ").forEach(function(el) {
//                          -------^^^^^-------
    el.style.display = "none";
});
```

---

For old browser support, you need to convert NodeList into Array since [`NodeList#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) not supports widely.

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("img,[href^='#cite'] ")).forEach(function(el) {
    el.style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, which supports `forEach`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach (except IE).

Answer (score 0):

1. query elements with href="#cite..."

   `document.querySelectorAll('[href^="#cite"]')`
2. query **tag a** elements with href="#cite..."

   `document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#cite"]')`